# Change the color of datagrid rows using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm building a wpf application using mvvm pattern.

I need help in changing the color of specifc rows in the Datagrid.

The DataGrid ItemsSource is binded to property of type Datatable in the ViewModel.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"/>
```

Also, i have a button with a Command binding

```
<Button Content="Run" Command="{Binding RunCommand}"/>
```

This is the RunCommand in my ViewModel

```
RunCommand = new DelegateCommand(Run, CanRun);
```

The Run method handles the execution.

in this method i'm iterating over the DataRows of the Data and based on some calculation that i do, i would like to set the color of each row in the datagrid.

green for pass and red for failure.

```
  foreach (DataRow row in Data.Rows){
      bool result=Calculate(row);
      if(result){
      SetTheRowColor(row,green);
      }
      else{
      SetTheRowColor(row,red);
      }
    }
```

So I need help on implementing that SetRowColor method.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of a particular column of the `DataTable` in your code and use a `DataTrigger` to change the colour of the row in the XAML markup, e.g.:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourColumn}" Value="somevalue">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

**Code:**

```
foreach (DataRow row in Data.Rows) {
    if (row["name"]==Somthing){
        row["YourColumn"] = "somevalue";
    }
}
```

Comment: what you mean in row["YourColumn"] ? the Datatable does not have a column of color, and i dont want to change the Datatable for styling purpose .

Comment: Then you shouldn't bind directly to the `DataTable`. You need to store the value somewhere. If you don't want to edit the `DataTable`, then create a (view)model class and populate instances of this with values from the `DataTable`. Binding to types that you cannot, or don't want to, modify for one reason or another is rarely a good idea when it comes to implementing the MVVM pattern or GUIs in general.

Comment: okay.Lets Say i will store the value for row color in dictionary where the row is the key and the color is the value. so i will add to the viewodel a dictionary<DataRow,string>.

Whats next how i bind each row with its color ?

Comment: Why would you want to store a `DataRow` in a dictionary? Add a `Color` property of type string and bind directly to this one?

Comment: because each row have a different color. i edited the question, i hope it's more understandable what i would like to accomplish.

Comment: The answer is the same, i.e. add a column or property to your model that defines the colour of the row in the view.  You need to store the information per row somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the ViewModel

The Following :

```
 private Dictionary<DataRow, Brush>? _rowColors;
 public Dictionary<DataRow, Brush>? RowsColor
    {
        get { return _rowColors; }
        set
        {
            _rowColors = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

 private void SetRowColor(DataRow row, SolidColorBrush color)
    {
        RowsColor[row] = color;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(RowsColor));

    }
```

Add this new class:

```
public class RowColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length == 2 && values[0] is Dictionary<DataRow, Brush> rowColors && values[1] is DataRowView rowView)
        {
            if (rowColors.Count != 0)
            {
                Brush value = rowColors.GetValueOrDefault(rowView.Row, Brushes.White);
                return value;
            }
        }

        return Brushes.White;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And Finally in the View  edit the datagrid to be:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding  Data.DefaultView}"
                      CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
               
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <converter:RowColorConverter x:Key="RowColorConv"/>
                </DataGrid.Resources>

                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RowColorConv}">
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext.RowsColor" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}"/>
                                    <Binding/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
```